# Quartz.net and clock changes

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I've been having some issues with the Quartz scheduler. We run an application that uses Quartz internally on a very wide variety of machines.  Our use case is not so much to run tasks at any particular time or date, but rather to run them in intervals with varying start times.

On some machines (particularly virtual machines), the internal clock is changed shortly after start-, or wake-up but after our application has started. This can cause tasks to either fire out of order, or mis-fire entirely. The last thing could possibly be fixed by using misfire triggers but the first one seems more complicated.

Any suggestions for working around this with Quartz? Right now our options appear to be to replace Quartz entirely with a homespun system or hopefully another library that is StopWatch (or similar) based. Thanks.

Comment: This may not really help anyone but we gave up on Quartz, and re-implemented a scheduler based off CPU ticks instead. It's probably nowhere near as scalable but we've been running hundreds of thousands of instances of it over the last six months with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to schedule a new job after you know that the clock is set properly. This will "reset" the schedule of jobs. Anything that is already running won't be affected though.